# Issue when I tried to add watermark using HTML code on my every post on blogspot

Tags: blogger, watermark, blogspot

I have a blog. When I post on it then I am afraid of if anyone copies it without giving me credit. So I tried to add watermark behind my text and I found one code as mentioned below:

```
.hbzwatermark::before {
display: block;
background: url("Put URL of your image to be used as watermark");
position: absolute;
height: 200%;
bottom: -100%;
left: 0%;
width: 5000%;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform-origin: left center;
-moz-transform-origin: left center;
-webkit-transform-origin: left center;
content: "";
z-index: -1;
background-size: auto 30px;
opacity: 0.1;
background-repeat: repeat;
}
.hbzwatermark {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
}
```

I found this during searching on Google and now don't remember the website.
When I use this code then numbering in my post is reset to 0 after 9 as shown in the image below

[With Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uqmuf.jpg)
But when I remove the above code then my numbering is normal as shown below:

[Without Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFMKS.jpg)

What is the matter? What wrong in this code?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I belive **overflow: hidden;** is causing the issue

Make it **overflow: visible;**

Comment: You're welcome. Do you mind marking it as the "right answer" ?